# VIewPager in recycler view does not load data onResume

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I have added a `ViewPager` in `RecyclerView`. The issue is that, if i press Home Button, or set activity to pause state, and resume activity again, it does not load fragments inside the view pager.

ViewPager tabs are there, but fragments loads blank.

When i debugged, i find out that, onCreateView does not get called in viewPager's fragment, when onResume() is called for activity,

Following is my code in RecyclerAdapter.

```
  private fun bindTabViewHolder(viewHolder: HomeRecyclerAdapter.TabViewHolder, position: Int) {


    viewHolder.tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewHolder.viewPager)

    //Creating View Pager Adapter Instance
    viewPagerAdapter = BaseViewPagerAdapter(fragmentManager)
    

    viewPagerAdapter?.addFragment(homeFragment, dataList?.get(position)?.teamName) // this line can crash
    viewPagerAdapter?.addFragment(awayFragment, dataList?.get(1)?.teamName) // this line can crash

    viewHolder.viewPager.adapter = viewPagerAdapter

}
```

I think if it starts calling `onCreateView()` for fragments, issue will be resolved, Also if i try to get fresh data from the feed, by pull to refresh, if does not load fragments inside viewPager.

Answer (score 0):

You should generally never put a ViewPager that hosts Fragments inside a RecyclerView, as the IDs / tags in the FragmentManager will get confused.

You will need to use a ViewPager in the RecyclerView that hosts Views (by subclassing PagerAdapter, instead of FragmentPagerAdapter) instead.